# ¿Porque me dice la consola que no está definida la función?

Tags: javascript, html

el código consiste en almacenar las interacciones realizadas y está dividido en cuatro archivos 3 js y un html

el mensaje de error

main.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: storage.temp.interactions.liked.content.append is not a function
at like (main.js:10)
at HTMLLIElement. (main.js:14)

el html

```html
<li id="l1">like</li>
<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "main.js";
    script.type = "module"
    script.async = "true";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
</script>
```

el main.js

```js
'use strict';
import * as storage from './modules/storage.js';

storage.init();
console.log(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('interactions')));

//project actions
const like = (id, like) => {
  document.getElementById(like).classList.toggle('liked');//para añadir unos estilos al li
  console.log(storage.temp.interactions.liked.content.append(id));//para actualizar los datos
}

document.getElementById('l1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    like('some project','l1')
});
```

el archivo ./modules/storage.js

```js
'use strict';
import {hash} from './data-structures.js';

const protointeractions = {
  opened: new hash(),
  commented: new hash(),
  liked: new hash(),
  disliked: new hash()
};

export const init = () => {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('interactions', JSON.stringify(protointeractions));
};

export const temp = {
  interactions: JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('interactions'))
}
export const update = (where, value) => {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem(where, JSON.stringify(value));
};
```

el archivo data-structures.js

```js
'use strict';

export class hash{
  constructor () {
    this.max = null;
    this.min = null;
    this.content = [];
  }
  set push (id) {
    this.content.append(id)
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hace esto `like('some project','l1')` y dónde está definido?

Comment: se supone que añade una clase al elemento con id 'l1' y después accede al campo interactions del localStorage por medio del módulo de storage.js, y en ese campo accede al subcampo liked, que es una estructura hash definida en data-structures.js, para añadirle el str 'some project' al array anidado en la estructura

Comment: Pero ¿esa función `like` está definida en alguna parte?  No me suena que sea propia de JS.

Comment: esta definida en el main.js

Comment: Quizá tienes que ponerlo así: `liked('some project','l1')` si se refiere al hash de `storage.js`

Comment: Eso me da el error de que la función liked no está definida, el problema se encuentra en que no detecta el append como una función

Comment: Prueba a cambiarlo por `appendChild()` pues `append` es jQuery me parece y para que funcione deberías incluir jQuery y declarar el elemento con la notación `$` de jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás usando un método no definido para los objetos de tipo `Array`. El tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) no posee ningún método llamado `append`. Por eso te da el error que obtienes.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, suponiendo que deseas añadir el valor de `id` a tu lista en `content`, podrías usar el método [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) del tipo `Array`.

Tu código para el método `like` podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
//project actions
const like = (id, like) => {
  document.getElementById(like).classList.toggle('liked');//para añadir unos estilos al li
  console.log(storage.temp.interactions.liked.content.push(id));//para actualizar los datos (se usa push)
}
```

Igualmente debes cambiar el [`setter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/set) llamado `push` de tu clase `hash`, ya que cometes el mismo error de intentar usar `append` sobre un tipo `Array`.

El método de tu clase deberías escribirlo así:

```js
//...
  set push(id) {
    this.content.push(id);
  }
//...
```

Y lo podrías usar en tu método `like` de esta forma:

```js
//project actions
const like = (id, like) => {
  document.getElementById(like).classList.toggle('liked');//para añadir unos estilos al li
  console.log(storage.temp.interactions.liked.push = id);//para actualizar los datos (se usa push)
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.